# How to increase height on IonTabBar?

Tags: css, reactjs, ionic-framework

My IonTabBar is being covered always by iOS notches on the phone.  How do I increase the size of the `IonTabBar` so it is above any notches?

I'm working on this stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-react-demo?file=index.js

I've added onto *variables.css* the following:

```
  ion-tab-bar {
    --height: 1000px;
    --min-height: 1000px;
  }
```

and nothing happens.

Here is a screenshot of my issue:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YH5k7.jpg

commenter said that footer could handle iPhone notches but I've tried to add `IonFooter` but no matter where I add it, then the app doesn't load.  I kind of have a complicated router setup (abbreviated):

App.js

```
  <IonApp>
    <IonReactRouter>
    <Route path="/" component={isLoggedIn ? Maintabs : UnloggedinRoutes} />
    </IonReactRouter>
  </IonApp>
```

Maintabs.js

```
        <IonTabs>
        
        <IonRouterOutlet>
          <Redirect exact path="/" to="/profile" />
         
        </IonRouterOutlet>
        <IonTabBar className="stylebar" slot='bottom'>
          <IonTabButton color='black' tab='Profile' href='/profile'>
        <IonIcon icon={ellipse} />
        <IonLabel>Profile</IonLabel>
          </IonTabButton>
          <IonTabButton tab='Leaflet' href='/leafletMap'>
        <IonIcon icon={triangle} />
        <IonLabel>Map</IonLabel>
          </IonTabButton>
            </IonTabBar>

      </IonTabs>
```

I've tried adding `IonFooter` all over and didn't get anywhere.

Comment: you can add screenshot?? as ionic tabs, header and footer auto handle iphone notches. and you dont have to do anytinng.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib updated thanks.  Not sure where to put `<IonFooter>`

Comment: that is an old template, hope you upgraded all of your packages

Comment: @AaronSaunders  Thanks just upgraded to ionic 6/react 17 and still having the same issue